# RPC solana node synchronization for only send tx

Tags: rpc, validator

I configured a simple solana RPC node on a virtual machine with:

- 56 CPUS
- 512 GB Ram
- 2xHD 2T
- 1GB Bandwidth
- Solana version 1.18.4
- Shred Version 50093

custom sysctl.conf
fs.file-max = 1000000
net.core.somaxconn = 65535
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 65535
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 30
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1

but after a few hours it starts to lose synchronization by losing 1 slot per second

this is the startup of the node

```
#!/bin/bash 
export RUST_BACKTRACE=1
export LimitNOFILE=1000000

exec solana-validator \
--identity /home/sol/validator-keypair.json \
--known-validator 6SNDPR8ranTLya8cZys326YsaQG2GXoXWD21GicJ7gLy \
--known-validator B7h5mmY3SS2a8qUvM8v5JQ3FKUhyWpH3D2vuKqE1x5Ww \
--known-validator Dwv3Ly5hvC43QyWSnufXM9qhpS2FVq4nNRhQ5vJZP8eB \
--known-validator 9Ys4eJZKcMyAHWv41hVSDRCKbW56iMNtYHD1VYWVVrN \
--only-known-rpc \
--full-rpc-api \
--no-voting \
--ledger /mnt/ledger \
--accounts /mnt/accounts \
--log /home/sol/solana-rpc.log \
--rpc-port 8899 \
--rpc-bind-address 172.100.0.55 \
--private-rpc \
--dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 \
--entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
--entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
--entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
--entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
--entrypoint entrypoint5.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
--wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record \
--limit-ledger-size \
--expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d \
```

my goal is only to send TX i don't need to vote and get accouts information.

How can I figure out where the bottleneck is and more importantly what configurations should I put in there to lighten the information to receive in order to keep the node aligned?

Comment: Hi. What cpu are you using, and what’s  the base clock on it?

Comment: Architecture:                       x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                     32-bit, 64-bit
Address sizes:                      43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                             56
On-line CPU(s) list:                0-55
Thread(s) per core:                 1
Core(s) per socket:                 1
Socket(s):                          56
NUMA node(s):                       2
CPU family:                         6
Model:                              79
Model name:                         Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v4 @ 2.40GHz

Comment: the strange thing is that out of 512GB of ram, it uses about 60GB

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU is too slow. A base clock of 2.4 GHz will not cut it for mainnet. According to the official documentation, you want at least a 2.8 GHz base clock.